# get minimum value that applied to condition in the most efficient way

Tags: sql, postgresql

i would like to choose minimal date of records with same id's but **with a condition in it**.
for instance how old those records are, what im doing now is joining the table to itself and applying the id's and the desired condition, it works but very slowly.

for instance:
i got t1:

| uid | vid | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-10-23 20:57:03.100 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-10-23 21:02:22.700 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-10-23 22:20:09.437 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-10-23 10:58:05.447 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-10-23 11:36:23.949 |

and this is the desired result with condition of half an hour **maximum** range between dates with the same id's:
(In other words - im looking for the most efficient way to get the minimal date with same id's that smaller than the date_created column in half an hour maximum.)

| uid | vid | date_created | dc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-10-23 20:57:03.100 | 2021-10-23 20:57:03.100 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-10-23 21:02:22.700 | 2021-10-23 20:57:03.100 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-10-23 22:20:09.437 | 2021-10-23 22:20:09.437 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-10-23 10:58:05.447 | 2021-10-23 10:58:05.447 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-10-23 11:36:23.949 | 2021-10-23 11:36:23.949 |

Answer (score 0):

For your specific condition "half an hour maximum range between dates with the same id's" you can use a `window` function. You can try something like this :

```
SELECT uid, vid, date_created
     , first(date_created) over (partition by uid order by date_created range between '30 minutes' preceding and current row) as dc
  FROM your_table
```